# Coexistence of Groovy- and Go gvm

Tags: groovy, go, gvm

I have Groovy GVM installed.  Trying to install the Golang version gave

```
ERROR: Already installed!
```

The problem is that `~/.gvm` already exists.

How do/should you make them both coexist today?

Are there any plans to resolve this conflict?

Comment: The Groovy project managers pitch Groovy as a "JVM language", meaning "JVM only", and treat other possible platforms for Groovy, including a Go-based edition, as threats to their own control of Groovy the brand. They actively work to promote the JVM, and criticize other platforms. They're unlikely, therefore, to bother resolving the naming conflict with Golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Issue 82](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/82) and [issue 103](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/103) seem to show there is no immediate plan to resolve that collision.

You find trace of that folder in:

- [`binscripts/gvm-installer`](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/blob/e5a06b52c76da676e5b42d1f0597e2ba1ee74790/binscripts/gvm-installer#L50):

  ```
  [ "$GVM_DEST" = "$HOME" ] && GVM_NAME=".gvm"
  ```
- [`bin/gvm`](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/blob/e5a06b52c76da676e5b42d1f0597e2ba1ee74790/bin/gvm#L12)

  ```
  [[ -s "$HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm"
  ```

You would need to patch the all Go GVM program to make sure `.gvm` isn't used.

Update March 2016: as mentioned in [issue 82](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/82#issuecomment-213233654):

> GVM is superseded by http://sdkman.io/. `gvm` command became `sdk`.

Comment: Has anyone attempted to get Groovy to address the conflict? Your first link shows that the Go tool came first, but both links are addressed at the Go tool.

Comment: @Jayan Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @VonC: great.  Cleared my answer :)